# What is "superficial gravity"

Tags: gravity, terminology, white-dwarf

I have seen the term superficial gravity used and it seems to be equivalent to surface gravity

seen, e.g., here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02295

Is there any difference between superficial and surface gravity? When should one be using one or the other?

Comment: The author is Portuguese. In Portuguese, "surface" is "superfície". If you look at the equations, you'll see that the definition ($\log g$) corresponds to "surface gravity". I suspect the standard term has been lost in translation.

Comment: @pela even in English the word "superficial" means "on (or above) the surface."

Comment: The author in not Portuguese. Brazilian, instead. But he speaks Portuguese, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "superficial" means "on the surface," so "superficial gravity" is the same as surface gravity. As @pela pointed out in the comments, the author of the article is Portuguese and in that language the word for surface is 'superficie.'